# Eclipse 100%+ CPU usage with specific workspace

Tags: eclipse, cpu-usage, eclipse-luna

I'm using Eclipse Luna. As soon as I open this workspace java CPU usage goes to over 100% and doesn't go down. Doesn't happen with other workspaces. I tried several things, and they don't work:

1. Running `./eclipse -clean`
2. Deleting the `org.eclipse.core.resources` folder in the `.metadata/.plugins` directory of the workspace and then reimporting all the projects into the workspace: this seemed to work yesterday, but today the workspace is freezing again.

[image: Java CPU usage]

I forgot to mention, it's not just CPU usage, the main problem is that the workspace is freezing and I can't do any action (can't edit code, can't open files, etc...). I think there's something corrupted with this workspace, because other workspaces work fine without increasing RAM availability. Tried the `-Xmx` thing, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java programming. I think it should be ask in some other site of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @OO7 I don't get that comment, Stackoverflow is not specifically for Java programming. And the rules give leniency to asking questions about tooling related to programming, which Eclipse surely is.

Comment: I think he meant that the `java` tag (now removed) was out of place, neverthelss I think the question fits here.

Comment: @Gimby Sorry, last line is wrong. I mean to say, it should be in some other tag defined here.

Answer (score 1):

%CPU usage is fine showing more than 100% by using top command, doesn't mean that you are in trouble until its too high.

Actually Your eclipse need more memory to run.
you should run eclipse by passing Xmx args with more memory

```
./eclipse [normal arguments] -vmargs -Xmx1256M [more VM args]
```

Comment: Please refer to the edited question. I added some information, this solution doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk unfortunately the information you provide is only proof that you have a problem. There can be any number of reasons for this problem to happen. For example on my windows machine it tends to happen when something triggers an exception while the workspace settings are being saved, for example when I leave a server runtime running. That is but one possibility of endless possibilities.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to debug this situation more accurately and get more information? The thing is that it's just the way I said it: as soon as I open that specific workspace Eclipse freezes.

Comment: Run eclipse with new workspace and import the projects from old workspace and try.o

Comment: @prashant thakre Creating new workspace isn't a good solution until u say there is no way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @OO7 actually I am just providing him the debugging steps. once he will perform the above steps only then he can reach to some conclusion like something wrong with Porject or workspace or really with M/C.